# How to get the String (label) of a Vertex by clicking on it (Jgraph)?

Tags: label, gettext, vertex, jgraph

In jgraph, is there a function similiar to the .getText(); for a vertex?
I need to get the text attached to them in the label.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example prints you the label of the vertex if you right click on it.

```java
graphComponent.getGraphControl().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
{
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 
    {
        if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e))
        {       
            mxCell cell =(mxCell) getGraphComponent().getCellAt(e.getX(), e.getY());

            if(cell != null)
            {
                System.out.println(cell.getValue().toString());
            }
        }
   }
});
```